# Why is there extra text in my output? How do I remove it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
# Plot the follwing plot and place th etitle as shown: 
x = np.array([80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125])
y = np.array([240, 250, 260, 270, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320, 330])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('Sports Watch Data', loc = 'left')
plt.ylabel('Calorie Burnage')
plt.xlabel('Average Pulse')
```

My output is showing

```
Text(0.5, 0, 'Average Pulse')
```

and then I see the chart. How do I remove this text?

Comment: This is the output of the last cell (the X label object), you can hide it by adding a `;` in the end of the last line